# Страница при первой загрузки должна быть не главной React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Здраствуйте есть ли возможность при первой загрузки страницы сделать чтоб изначально загружалась не главная страница, а какая-то другая в React.js используя только возможности react-router-dom 6, может какой нибудь атрибут к примеру?

Comment: не совсем понятно что вам надо, если честно

Comment: Допустим есть 3 страницы главная/каталог/контакты, и к примеру что когда переходишь на ссылке site.com то тебе сразу показывало не главную страницу а редиректило на site.com/catalog

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#adding-a-no-match-route